# How can I substring a git command in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, git

I'm trying to add a pre-commit hook in TurtoiseGit to automatically add the JIRA number in my commit message. The JIRA number is always the first part of my branch name.

For example: `JIRA-456-fix-cleanup-crash`, I would like to have `JIRA-456`

The git command I'm using is `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD > %2`. But unfortunately this give me the whole branch name. I only need `JIRA-456`.

I tried using the shell command `findstr` to substring the branch name without success.

The mechanism I use is the one listed here:
https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2229#note_1781864

Comment: So what is your question and where are you stuck?

Comment: @gronostaj I added clarification. I hope this explains my problem a little better. :)

Comment: Reword your question - this isn't about `git` at all, but more like "_How do I get `JIRA-456` from `JIRA-456-fix-cleanup-crash` in a batch file?_"

Comment: @Attie I specified git since maybe there is a git command that could also help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting the output of

```
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

directly into a file `> %2`, parse it with a [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=-" %%A in ('
    git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
') Do Set "Var=%%A-%%B"
(Echo:%Var%)>%2
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if the structure of the string is like you said `AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-...`.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ("JIRA-456-fix-cleanup-crash") do (set "expectedString=%%a-%%b")
echo %expectedString%
```

Yields `JIRA-456`, it works by splitting the string using `-` as a delimiter, then it takes the `tokens` `1`(`%%a`) and `2`(`%%b`) and concatenate them using `set`, so you can make use of the string further in your batch file.

So, for you command you will need to pass the command to the `FOR` function in it's own context using single quotes `'`

```
:: I Haven't used git so I'm not really sure about why you redirected the output stream
:: but this should give you a good idea how to use it

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%a in ('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD') do (set "ExString=%%a-%%b")
```

The `%%a` syntax is for batch files if you want to test it as a command use `%a`

Cheers.